# Signing PDFs with iTextSharp Luna HSM - Hello world

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, hsm

I'm trying to sign a PDF with a Luna HSM and have been given the following code:

```
public class Sign
{
    private const string _reason = "Test seal by eSignatur";
    private const string _location = "Copenhagen, Denmark";
    private const int _estimatedSize = 0;
    private readonly X509Certificate2 _certificate;
    private readonly ICollection<X509Certificate> _chain;
    private readonly IOcspClient _ocspClient;
    private readonly ICollection<ICrlClient> _crlList;
    private readonly ITSAClient _tsaClient;

    public Sign(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        _certificate = certificate;
        _chain = GetChain();
        _ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
        _crlList = new List<ICrlClient> { new CrlClientOnline(_chain) };
        _tsaClient = GetTsaClient(_chain);
    }

    private ICollection<X509Certificate> GetChain()
    {
        var x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var x509Chain = new X509Chain();
        x509Chain.Build(_certificate);

        var chain = (
        from X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509Chain.ChainElements
        select DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate)).ToList();
        x509Store.Close();
        return chain;
    }

    private ITSAClient GetTsaClient(IEnumerable<X509Certificate> chain)
    {
        return (from cert in chain
                select CertificateUtil.GetTSAURL(cert)
                    into tsaUrl
                    where tsaUrl != null
                    select new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void Execute(string dest)
    {
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(GeneratePDF()))
        {
            using (var os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');

                    var appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                    appearance.Reason = _reason;
                    appearance.Location = _location;
                    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 1, string.Format("seal-{0}", DateTime.Now));

                    var pks = new X509Certificate2Signature(_certificate, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
                    MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, _chain, _crlList, _ocspClient, _tsaClient, _estimatedSize, CryptoStandard.CMS);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm then referencing a certificate that I have been issued and it appears to be installed correctly and has a corresponding private key which I'm able to view with `certmgr.msc`. I'm referencing it by it's thumbprint.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);     
    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certificates = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        foreach (var certificate in certificates)
        {
            if (certificate.Thumbprint.ToString() == "123456")
            {
                cert = certificate;
            }
        }

        Sign Signer = new Sign(cert);
        Signer.Execute(string.Format(@"G:\Delete\{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", "").Replace(@"/", "")));
    }
    finally 
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/iText - HSM' Application.
>   The keyset is not defined.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The keyset is not defined.

```
Source Error: 


Line 97:                         appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 1, string.Format("seal-{0}", DateTime.Now));
Line 98:                         
Line 99:                         var pks = new X509Certificate2Signature(_certificate, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
Line 100:                        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, _chain, _crlList, _ocspClient, _tsaClient, _estimatedSize, CryptoStandard.CMS);
Line 101:
```

I would really appreciate some guidance on what I should be doing i.e. am I using the correct certificate?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I only know how to do this in Java, but looking at your code and the error, I'd say that there's no key in your key store (`StoreName.My`) on your machine (`StoreLocation.LocalMachine`). Are you sure you have a Luna HSM on your Windows machine? I thought most of the HSMs were on Linux servers (it's the logical choice: I use Windows on the desktop; Linux on the server).

Comment: Three questions: 1. Are you running your code on IIS? 2. What identity does your application pool use? 3. Does your code work with some other certificate located in the same store but managed by different CSP (not stored in HSM but for example imported from PKCS#12 file)? @BrunoLowagie It is actually pretty common practice to use HSM on Windows platform. Most of the times it can be accessed by exactly the same APIs as most of the smartcards - MS CryptoAPI and/or PKCS#11.

Comment: Hi both, thank you for your quick responses.
To clarify, I’m connecting to a remotely hosted HSM  and have installed client software. I can confirm connectivity. I’ve followed an installation guide and created a CSR with the HSM, requested a certificate from a certificate provider using the CSR and have received and installed the certificates on my local machine.

Comment: The trial certificate shows that it has a private key associated with it and all other certificates in the chain.  This is all running on Windows 7-64 and it’s a test project running in Visual Studio. I have already adjusted the permission for the private key giving widespread permission - I will try running it on IIS.
Using another trial certificate (without a CSR being required) works using exactly the same code as above. 
I’m trying to understand if I need to do anything other than specify the trial certificate during signing and / or if there is a problem with my setup.

Comment: I was asking questions 1 and 2 because your application seems to be a web application and you are looking for the signing certificate in the CurrentUser store which is specific to your user account and won't be available in IIS unless the application pool runs under your account - but that seems not to be your current issue. If I understand your comment correctly you have confirmed that your code works with some other certificate from the same store which most likely indicates a problem with your setup.

Comment: Guess#1: You may be using incorrect certificate - try to use `cert = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, null, null, X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)[0];` to select the certificate from GUI. Guess#2: Your certificate may be incorrectly paired with the private key - try to use `certutil -repairstore` command to fix that. Guess#3: There may also be some problem with the HSM setup. Is any other application able to use that certificate/key?

Comment: #2: I have ran this command already as the initial install of the certificate didn't have the private key.

#3: I don't have any other programs to test with ATM. Are any tools that I could use?

#1: I won't have access to the test environment for a few days but will definitely try this.

I will update when I have tested suggestions and set-up within IIS. Thanks again

Comment: If your HSM is on a server, why would you expect your remote machine to have access to the private key on the server? That sounds illogical to me.

Comment: My understanding is that the private key is held on the remote HSM and the one paired with the certificate is part of the local client software install. It was specified in the installation guide that I received  and I believe it is integral part of the process of sending a hash to the remote module to be signed?

Comment: @user1024416 I have posted an answer with the source code of a very simple console application which creates a CMS signature with your certificate and as such can be used to test whether you setup is OK.

Comment: Open the `certmgr.msc`; find your certificate; right click it. Select `Manage Private Keys` and add the user to the ACL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compile and run following sample application which creates CMS signature with the certificate (and private key) you select from the UI:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Store certStore = null;
            X509Certificate2 signingCertificate = null;

            // Select signing certificate
            try
            {
                certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(certStore.Certificates, null, null, X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
                if (certCollection == null || certCollection.Count < 1)
                    throw new Exception("No certificate selected");

                signingCertificate = certCollection[0];
                if (!signingCertificate.HasPrivateKey)
                    throw new Exception("Selected certificate is not associated with a private key");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (certStore != null)
                    certStore.Close();
            }

            // Create CMS signature with selected certificate
            byte[] dataToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world");
            ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(dataToSign);
            CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signingCertificate);
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, false);
            signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
            byte[] signature = signedCms.Encode();

            // Parse and verify CMS signature (without certification path checking)
            SignedCms signedCms2 = new SignedCms();
            signedCms2.Decode(signature);
            signedCms2.CheckSignature(true);
        }
    }
}
```

If this application fails to create a signature then most likely there is a problem with your HSM setup (for example the certificate may be incorrectly paired with the private key).

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The keyset is not defined.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.PkcsUtils.CreateSignerEncodeInfo(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.Sign(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner signer)
   at ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in G:\xyz
- Console

Comment: App\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 40

Thank you for the code @jaric. I've ran the above code and I get the following: 


I ran the console app as the same user that installed the certificate. The provider says that there is nothing wrong with the install.

Comment: @user1024416 IMO this confirms that your problem is not iText related as your certificate seems to be generally unusable on your machine. I believe your best shot is to return to the installation guide you have mentioned in your previous comment and setup HSM again.